# Copy a file from Module1 to a directory in Module2

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have following task in `build.gradle` under one of my module :

```
def output = "build/MobileFramework-Android.${version}/"

task myRelease(type: Copy, dependsOn: ':test:assembleRelease') {
    from(project(':test').file('build/intermediates/outputs/apk/'))
    into("$output")
    include('test-release.apk')
    rename('test-release.apk', 'apptm.apk')
}
```

The porpose is to copy a file from `test Module` to another module which includes build.gradle.

For some reason myRelease task is not working as I expected. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistakenly specified the `from` path. The right path is:

```
from(project(':test').file('build/outputs/apk/'))
```